# Rt index String update

Tags: string, sphinx

How to Update the String attributre in RT Index? And also how to declare multi value attibute (MVA)

example like  integer/string attribute

```
rt_attr_uint    = field1
rt_attr_string  = field2
```

Answer (score 0):

Right now, there is no UPDATE support for string attributes. You can only replace the whole row.

Declaring a MVA on a RT index is very simple, works just the same as any other attribute, but remember its numeric only.

```
rt_attr_multi = my_tags
```

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current.html#conf-rt-attr-multi